# QT 5 connect() function to connect the textEditor and the MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

I am learning Qt 5 with some example code from web, but I cannot compile it. I have several files as:
in mainwindow.h, I have my code:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    QTextEdit *textEdit;
};
```

The implementation of the class is in mainwindow.cpp, as

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    setWindowTitle("TextPad [*]");
    textEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    setCentralWidget(textEdit);
    connect(textEdit,&QTextEdit::textChanged,this,this->setWindowModified(true));
}
```

And in my main.cpp, it is quite simple, as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

What I want to do is the have a "*" in the window title, if I have changed the text in the textEditor, so I use a connect() function. The problem I cannot compile it correctly, the error message is as

```
error: invalid use of void expression
     connect(textEdit,&QTextEdit::textChanged,this,this->setWindowModified(true));
```

Any help are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
connect(textEdit,&QTextEdit::textChanged,this,this->setWindowModified(true));
```

to

```
connect(textEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged()),this,SLOT(myTextChanged()));
//or you can use alternate form
connect(textEdit,&QTextEdit::textChanged,this,myTextChanged);
```

and define a slot

```
void MainWindow::myTextChanged() {
    setWindowModified(true);
}
```

`connect()` requires only either the name of the signal/slot (using the words `SIGNAL` and `SLOT`) or a pointer to it, using the function pointer style, so you cannot place code to execute in a `connect()` call. Instead define an extra slot to implement the desired behavior, as shown.

Comment: Thanks, I applied your second method, and it works correctly. You just have one typo in the code, but quite easy to find out from compiling.

Comment: @zhoudingjiang - Sorry for the typo. I don't currently have access to Qt, so I can't compile. Is it fixed now?