# QT : No such slot - Newbie here

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt4

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "QProgressBar"
#include "QPushButton"
#include "QHBoxLayout"
#include "QLabel"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

QApplication a(argc, argv);
QWidget *mainw = new QWidget;
mainw->setWindowTitle("Progress Increase");
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout();
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("PRESS TO INCREASE");
QLabel *newlabel = new QLabel();
newlabel->setText("WILL CHANGE HERE");
QObject::connect(button,SIGNAL(pressed()),newlabel,SLOT(setText("GAMA     GAMA")));
layout->addWidget(button);
layout->addWidget(newlabel);

mainw->setLayout(layout);
mainw->show();
return a.exec(); 
}
```

QT is giving following error.I am newbie
QObject::connect: No such slot QLabel::setText("GAMA GAMA") in ..\Gaama\main.cpp:18

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT 5 connect() function to connect the textEditor and the MainWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815005/qt-5-connect-function-to-connect-the-texteditor-and-the-mainwindow)

Comment: you can't just pass the values directly like that with the `connect` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to check the documentation on [QObject::connect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-3) Qt has a very good documentation that is easy to navigate around and understand.

you're getting that error because the arguments for QObject::connect are
 - the object emitting the signal
 - the signal emitted
 - the receiving object
 - and the receiving method, called a slot
and you can't pass argument values to the signal and slot just only the type they take. Also the number of argument types the slot take must be equal or less than that of the signal.

so for example your code

```
QObject::connect(button,SIGNAL(pressed()),newlabel,SLOT(setText("GAMA     GAMA")));
```

should be

```
QObject::connect(button,SIGNAL(pressed()),newlabel,SLOT(setText()));
```

but that would again be wrong because there is no method QLable::setext()
I think what your looking for is

```
QObject::connect(button,SIGNAL(pressed()),newlabel,SLOT(someSlot()));
```

then define `someslot()` and in there set the label's text to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> QObject::connect(button,SIGNAL(pressed()),newlabel,SLOT(setText("GAMA 
>   GAMA")));

If you want to create a handler for `QPushButton::pressed()` event, i.e. after a button was pressed a label text should be changed, you can

```
// Create a halper that transforms pressed() signal to textChanged(text) signal
// that will be connected to setText() slot, i.e.
// button.pressed() -> proxy.onButtonPressed() -> label.setText(text)
//
class SignalHelper : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    QString  text_;
public:
    SignalHelper(const QString & text)
            : text_(text) {
    }
signals:
    void textChanged(const QString & text);
public slots:
    void onButtonPressed() {
        emit textChanged(text_);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
...
// Connect
//
QScopedPointer<SignalHelper> pHelper(new SignalHelper(QStringLiteral("GAMA     GAMA")));

QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::pressed,
                 pHelper.data(), &SignalHelper::onButtonPressed);

QObject::connect(pHelper.data(), &SignalHelper::textChanged,
                 newlabel, &QLabel::setText);
...
// Also you can add another button that sets another text
//
QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("PRESS TO DECREASE");

QScopedPointer<SignalHelper> pHelper2(new SignalHelper(QStringLiteral("Decreased")));

QObject::connect(button2, &QPushButton::pressed,
                 pHelper2.data(), &SignalHelper::onButtonPressed);

QObject::connect(pHelper2.data(), &SignalHelper::textChanged,
                 newlabel, &QLabel::setText);

...
}
```

Another way is to use a signal handler + std::bind() - in this case you do not need to define any specific signal in a helper class, so you can attach any handler to pressed() signal.

```
typedef std::function<void()> Handler_t;

class BtnPressHandler : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Handler_t  handler_;
public:
    BtnPressHandler(Handler_t handler)
            : handler_(handler) {
    }
public slots:
    void onButtonPressed() {
        handler_();
    }
};

// Connect
//
QScopedPointer<BtnPressHandler> pHandler(new BtnPressHandler(
        std::bind(&QLabel::setText, newlabel, QStringLiteral("GAMA     GAMA"))));

QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::pressed,
                 pHandler.data(), &BtnPressHandler::onButtonPressed);

// Create a button that closes an application
//
QPushButton * exitBtn = new QPushButton("PRESS TO EXIT");

QScopedPointer<BtnPressHandler> pHandler2(new BtnPressHandler(
        std::bind(&QApplication::quit, &a)));

QObject::connect(exitBtn, &QPushButton::pressed,
                 pHandler2.data(), &BtnPressHandler::onButtonPressed);
```